# Bezeichnung für den Mittelwert zwischen Minimum und Maximum?

Tags: single-word-request, mathematics

Kleines Beispiel: Alice, Berta, Claudia und Doris werfen Bälle.

Wurfweiten:
Alice 10m
Berta 11m
Claudia (gestolpert) 2m
Doris 13m

Wenn ich nun wissen will, wie heute so geworfen wurde, berechne ich

```
(10m + 11m + 2m + 13m) / 4 = 9m
```

Das ist der **Mittelwert** (arithmetisches Mittel).

Der Wert ist aber verzerrt durch Claudias gerissenes Schuhband, daher bestimme ich stattdessen:

```
2m, 10m, 11m, 13m
        ^ = (10m + 11m) / 2 = 10,5m
```

Das ist der **Median**.

Wenn ich alle Bälle auf der Bahn fotografieren will, muss der Fotograf "die Mitte zwischen dem Ball ganz links und dem Ball ganz rechts" anpeilen und zoomen, bis er alle Bälle im Bild hat. Um diese "mittlere Stelle" zu ermitteln, muss ich rechnen:

```
(2m + 13m) / 2 = 7,5m
```

**Gibt es eine Bezeichnung für den Mittelwert aus Minimum und Maximum?**

Comment: Bereichsmittel (engl. Mid-range)

Comment: Wobei man bedenken sollte, das "Mittelwert" ohne nähere Angabe generell ein relativ unscharfer Begriff ist. Im Alltag ist oft das arithmetische Mittel gemeint, es gibt aber noch viele andere Definitionen. Zu den häufigeren gehören das geometrische Mittel, das quadratische Mittel oder das harmonische Mittel. Es kann also durchaus sinnvoll sein, einfach die Definition anzugeben.

Comment: @Olafant Wikipedia sagt tatsächlich so, aber ich meine doch was anderes gelernt zu haben. Ist nicht das Bereichsmittel der Durchschnitt zwischen dem kleinsten und höchsten *theoretischen* und nicht *tatsächlichen* Beobachtungswert? Wenn ich z.B. auf einem Skala von 1 bis 5 angeben soll wie gut mir irgendwas gefällt, ist mMn das Bereichsmittel immer 3, auch wenn niemand tatsächlich 1 oder 5 geantwortet hat.

Comment: @jambjo: Bereichsmittel ist richtig als Mittelwert der beobachteten Daten, das sagt nicht nur Wikipedia. Es kann natürlich sein, dass das Wort bei dieser Art Umfragen anders genutzt wird.
Willst du das nicht als Antwort posten, @Olafant? Die Frage ist damit aus meiner Sicht beantwortet, da muss ja nun niemand einen Aufsatz über Mittelwete schreiben.

Comment: Ich bin etwas überrascht über die hier genannte Definition des Medians, aber sie scheint weit verbreitet zu sein. In meinem Studium lernte ich noch als einen der zentralen Vorteile des Medians, dass er definitiv einen tatsächlich im Datensatz enthaltenen Wert ermittelt - also z.B. bei einem Datensatz wie (2, 2, 2, 98, 98, 98) eben gerade *keinen* "Kunstwert" wie 50 zurückliefert, der fernab jeglicher tatsächlich im Datensatz auftretender Werte liegt. Ggf. ist also zu beachten, dass der Begriff "Median" möglicherweise nicht ganz so eindeutig definiert ist.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Ich stimme dafür, diese Frage zu schließen, weil sie keine Frage nach einem Aspekt der deutschen Sprache ist, sondern nach einem mathematischen Begriff fragt.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Was dem Sinn der Tags *single-word-request* und *mathematics* entsprechen dürfte.

Comment: Das ist der Schwerpunkt der konvexen Hülle :)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Was wäre denn in deinem Beispiel der Median? Wenn die Anzahl der Beobachtungswerte gerade ist, bleibt nur das arithmetische Mittel der beiden mittleren Werte als Median. In deinem Beispiel also gerade (2+98)/2 = 50.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: D.h., die Frage nach einem mathematischen Begriff in Deutsch ist kein Aspekt der deutschen Sprache? Nach meinem Verständis ist die sichere und richtige Verwendung deutscher Begriffe samt und sonders ein Aspekt der deutschen Sprache. (abgesehen davon, dass math.SE nur Englisch spricht)

Comment: @Olafant: Der Median wäre dann entweder der größere oder der kleinere der zwei Werte. Das wird in der jeweiligen Verwendung als Konvention festgelegt. Das Essentielle dabei ist, dass man einen Wert ethält, der im Datensatz tatsächlich existiert. Als Beispiel wurde damals ein Produktentwurf für irgendwas Größenbezogenes genannt - wenn 50% der Kunden das Produkt 10cm groß brauchen und die anderen 50% es 70cm groß brauchen, produziert man auf Grundlage des Mittelwerts Müll (ein 40cm großes Produkt, das keiner haben will), aber auf Grundlage des Medians bedient man 50% des Markts.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Das verstehe ich nicht. Wenn 50% der Kunden das Produkt 10 cm groß und 50% es 70 cm groß brauchen, produziere ich es 10 cm oder 70 cm Größe. Dazu brauche ich keinen Median. Bei einer Liste wie 10, 10, 30, 40, 97, 98, 99 ist der Median 40. Damit bediene ich doch nicht 50% des Marktes. Wenn du die 40 weglässt, sind 30 und 97 genauso wenig hilfreich wie 63,5. Aber für beide Werte gilt, dass die eine Hälfte drunter, die andere Hälfte drüber liegt.

Comment: @Olafant: Die Annahme war, dass man diesen Überblick, dass es 10cm und 70cm als Werte gibt, eben nicht hat - weil in der Realität die gewünschten/benötigten Größen eben nicht exakt gleich groß sind, sondern man einen großen unüberschaubaren Haufen von Zahlen hat, denen man mit einer Aggregatfunktion bezukommen versucht. Und freilich gibt es Beispiele, wo auch der Median nicht hilft; die Aussage war lediglich, dass er im genannten Beispiel dem Mittelwert überlegen ist. Da das im Informatikstudium war, kann es aber eine vom Standard abweichende Definition von "Median" gewesen sein - ...

Comment: ... Informatiker bevorzugen mitunter diskrete Werte gegenüber kontinuierlichen, und überhaupt ist der Vorgang "die Mitte" in einer Liste zu errechnen, um dann _den nächstgelegenen ganzzahligen Index_ zu verwenden, eine in der Softwareentwicklung häufig eingesetzte Technik, weil man sehr häufig ein konkretes Listenelement haben will, keinen irgendwie gearteten Durchschnitt zwischen zwei Elementen.

Comment: @CarstenS Aber nur, wenn die Beobachtungswerte keine punktuelle Masse darstellen. ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Das arithmetische Mittel aus kleinstem und größtem Beobachtungswert wird **[Bereichsmittel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittelwert#Bereichsmittel)** genannt, auf Englisch *mid-range*.